# Proof of pointwise and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**I was wondering if someone could check my proof of pointwise and uniform convergence for the sequence $f_n=\bigl((1/n)+x^2\bigr)^{1/2}$**. By taking the limit of $f_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity, we see that the pointwise limit is the function $f(x)=(x^2)^{1/2}=|x|$.

Claim:The sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N$ such that $1/(N)^{1/2}<\epsilon$. Let $n\geq N$ and $x$ be real. Then,

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\Bigl|((1/n)+x^2)^{1/2}-(x^2)^{1/2}\Bigr|$$

Multiplying by its conjugate yields

$$\Bigl|1/\bigl[n\bigl((1/n)+x^2\bigr)^{1/2}+(x^2)^{1/2})\bigr)\bigr]\Bigr|\leq 1/(n)^{1/2}<=1/(N)^{1/2}<\epsilon.$$

Comment: I don't know how you arrive at the left hand term in the last estimate. If mulitplying by the conjugate refers to the identity $(a-b) (a+b) = a^2 - b^2$ then I would expect simply a term $1/n$ there. You should be careful with this multiplation, if you don't want to apply it to the lhs too, the factor needs to be $\ge 1$ (watch  out for small $x$).

Comment: In the numerator you are left with a^2-b^2=(1/n)+x^2-x^2=1/n.

Comment: but that's not what is written in your question.

Comment: Multiplying by the conjugate yields (1/n)*1/(sqrt((1/n)+x^2)+sqrt(x^2))<=1/sqrt(n)<=1/sqrt(N)<epsilon?

Comment: too complicated a formula for a comment, I've written an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

The rhs in your first displayed equation, times it's conjugate, is simply
$$\left|\left( (\frac{1}{n})+x^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}-\left(x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right| \times \left|\left( (\frac{1}{n})+x^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right| = \left( (\frac{1}{n})+x^2 \right)-x^2=\frac{1}{n}$$

This will in fact allow you to prove uniform convergence (for large $x$, see below).

The term you've got in the lhs of your last displayed equation 
$$|1/[n((1/n)+x^2)^{1/2}+ (x^{2})^{1/2})]|$$

seems to be very strange to me, even the $x$-term appears somehow in the denominator. Maybe it is due to a typo?

If you multiply with the conjugate 
$$\left|\left( (\frac{1}{n})+x^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right| $$

(as you call it), as mentioned earlier in my comment, you have to be aware of the fact that this is $<1$ for small $x$ and large $n$. In that case, when multiplying the rhs of your inequality, the inequality is not preserved. This means, for small $x$ you need a different reasoning.

Comment: I guess I should have said I multiplied the left hand side by the conjugate/conjugate to preserve the equality.That is how I got the term.Then used the fact that x^2>=0

Comment: You must not multiply the lhs by anything. You want to estimate it from above. If you multiply it, you get an estimate for something you don't want to estimate. Even if you'd do that, it would not produce the term you wrote down. Check the parenthesis.

Comment: If we fix n and take the derivative of fn(x),we see that the maximum is achieved at x=0 for every N that is a natural number.So fn(0)=(n)^(-1/2).Wouldn't this imply that the sequence is bounded above by (n)^(-1/2)?